# Cordova File Transfer download fails ios 9 - Response Code 200

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, file-transfer

I try to download a file with cordova.

These setting for ios: 
Cordova 6.3.1, file plugin  3.0.0, file transfer plugin  1.4.0, Xcode 7, ios 9.3.4 on test system

But also in a Windows 10 uwp-App.

The download works sometimes (mainly for smaller files) but fails to download the file in some other cases. So i assume the code in general works fine (and did so for the last year (with older Cordova versions).

A file gets created everytime and the response code is 200 so everything seems fine for my system, but the created file is only a few bytes large in size.

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory(folderName, {create: true}, function(dirEntry){
    var path = dirEntry.toURL() + '/' + fileName;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();        
    var uri = encodeURI(url) + '?' + new Date().getMilliseconds();
    ft.download(sessionurl, downloadPath, function(entry) {
       entry.file(

            function(file) {
                onsuccess(file);
            },
            function(error) {
                onerror(error);
            }
        );
}
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

After some checking I found the problem. My server delivers files via php. For larger files the allowed memory size was too small. To fix it I had to raise the allowed memory size on the server.